# Swing: How to paint focus-rectangle just like current LAF?

Tags: java, swing

This might be a long shot, but does anyone know of a way to paint the dotted line focus-rectangle on my custom component just like the current LAF components do?  I'm writing a custom component and I would like it's UI delegate to look very much like the Windows 7 LAF. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To paint a windows like dashed border use this Border class.

```
  import java.awt.Graphics;
  import java.awt.Insets;
  import javax.swing.UIManager;
  import javax.swing.border.Border;
  import java.awt.Component;


  public class DashedBorder implements Border {

    private static Insets EMPTY = new Insets(0,0,0,0);

    @Override
    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
      int vx, vy;

      g.setColor(UIManager.getDefaults().getColor("Button.focus"));

      // draw upper and lower horizontal dashes
      for (vx = x; vx < (x + width); vx += 2) {
        g.fillRect(vx, y, 1, 1);
        g.fillRect(vx, y + height - 1, 1, 1);
      }

      // draw left and right vertical dashes
      for (vy = y; vy < (y + height); vy += 2) {
        g.fillRect(x, vy, 1, 1);
        g.fillRect(x + width - 1, vy, 1, 1);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
      return EMPTY;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isBorderOpaque() {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Actually, I'm curious about that. I didn't see anything in the FAQ against answering old, unanswered questions.  This question still has no official answer. I used a different solution and didn't revisit Rastislav's answer below, which might be the official answer.  The answer above/here, however, is to a slightly different question than I was trying to ask ;)

Comment: Thanks for `UIManager.getDefaults().getColor("Button.focus")`. I didn't need any custom painting for my task, so I've just used `BorderFactory.createLineBorder` with the color taken from the `UIManager`.

Answer (score 2):

It will be tricky, but possible. E.g take a look to e.g. WindowsButtonUI. There is method called paintFocus and there are all information needed. As you can see the all values are read using `UIManager.get*(string)` methods where `string` is in form `button.*`. This is common convention used in UI defaults table.

Comment: That sounds a lot like what I'm looking for.  I'll try to dive in soon and take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Should be fairly easy by using appropriate [BasicStroke](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BasicStroke.html) and then creating a rectangualar shape using [createStrokedShape](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BasicStroke.html#createStrokedShape(java.awt.Shape)) method.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It may or may not use a dotted line at all.  And what if the look-and-feel gets tweaked later on?  I'd have to play cat-and-mouse.  I was hoping there was a publicly visible method for painting my component to be deactivated just as the current look and feel (whatever it is). Might be wishful thinking.

Comment: If you're trying to make your custom component look correct generically on any LAF then I'm afraid it is not possible. But it is possible to write specific UI for specific LAF to make it look correct.